# Minimum permissable load for a relay

Tags: relay

[image: Datasheet excerpt]

I understand the purpose of the minimum permissible load (for contact wetting) but I want to know the relationship between the voltage and the current. For instance, the above table states that the minimum load is 100 mA at 5VDC. What if I apply 10 mA but at 220VAC? Does that satisfy this condition?

Comment: AC wetting current MAY be lower than DC due to voltage reversals but sticking with the specified DC value would be afest in the absence of a formal spec. HOWEVER, wetting current requirement is also voltage dependant (as opposed to AC or DC issues) with higher voltages breaking down the oxide film. I'd GUESS that at 220 VAC you'd need zero wetting current.

Comment: And that is the condition to give the rated number of operations at the rated contact resistance: 220VAC could give you more expected operations before failure (wetting OK) or less (arcing not OK): and failure would mean higher than the expected contact resistance. Don't treat it as a warrenty that 220VAC will work: more as a warning that at 5V it won't work at less than 100mA.

Comment: @david how can I ensure that at 220VAC I will get the expected life? I am attempting to minimize arcing by switching near the zero-crossings. It has helped reduce the arcing.

Comment: No solution, either you find a relay that is specified for your use, or you test your selected relay (and buy from a full service supplier who notifies you of process changes). You are not the only engineer with this problem: Apollo 13 failed with a stuck relay, and my car (GM) has a stuck relay too.

Answer (score 2):

Once the relay is on, it doesn't really matter what the input voltage is since the switched contacts don't see that voltage anyways. However, in some cases once the contacts are wetted, the minimum permissible load requirement may be relaxed. For this reason, people sometimes use a capacitor at the output of the relay to demand a large transient current as the switch closes, meeting the requirement for contact wetting momentarily and then backing off. For a given capacitor, the profile of the current as the switch closes will depend on input voltage. Unfortunately, it seems your datasheet doesn't provide a lot of information about the wetting characteristics. I would conservatively take the information given to mean 100mA is always required, even once the switch is closed (and therefore regardless of the voltage). If you want to experiment and determine the wetting characteristics, however, you may be able to dodge the spec...